# Updating the manifest and overwriting duplicate entries using jar

Tags: java, jar, manifest

Is there a way to use a command like

```
jar ufm myfile.jar ManifestUpdates.mf
```

to update the manifest and overwrite any existing names?

Say `Permissions: all-permissions` exists in the original manifest and the ManifestUpdates.mf contains `Permissions: sandbox`, I want the manifest file inside the jar to have one line for `Permissions` that has `sandbox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I know it is not possible to simply replace any attribute of existing manifest.mf file. Either you need to unpack-edit-repack.

Alternatively [ant:jar](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) provide you some flexibility to merge two jars and manage duplicates. Using this you may merge two jar (one original and 2nd one with updated manifest).

Comment: I'll have to look into this more closely, but it may help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I just used 7zip (http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) to open the jar and navigated to the META-INF\ which contains the MANIFEST.MF. Once there I dragged and dropped the new MANIFEST and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

- Extract the existing manifest file using winrar and make your changes.
- Using winrar you can delete the manifest file inside the jar.
- Then you can use that command to put a new manifest inside.

Comment: When you are downvoting, please put a comment stating your reason.